# weirdly if else compares wrongly

Tags: php

```
$comet = $this->model->getActiveComet($userId);
$string = 'notificationComet';

if ($comet !== $string) {
    echo $comet;
    echo $string;
    echo "yes";exit;
  }
```

as shown in the code above, only if value of `$comet` doesn't match `$string` it should execute whatever inside the braces thus exit.

But both of them are having the same value which is **'notificationComet'**

I tested gettype() of both variables and they return string as type.
I used `!=` instead of `!==` , no difference.
if I change the condition to this: `if ($comet === $string)` the block inside   doesn't get executed.

I just don't understand why the condition is `true` for `if ($comet !== $string)` as they both hold the same value?

Please explain to me someone where I made mistake?

Comment: Did you try a `var_dump` on both `$comet` and `$string`?

Comment: can u show the value in `$comet` surely that may be the thing causing the error.

Comment: why not use `strcmp`

Comment: can you show var_dump of both variable that is :- $comet and $string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use the following...

```
$comet = $this->model->getActiveComet($userId);
$string = 'notificationComet';

if ( strpos($comet,$string) === FALSE ) {
    echo $comet;
    echo $string;
    echo "yes";exit;
  }
```

I believe that would work.

Comment: yes works...what's the problem and why must use strpos?

Comment: `strpos` is actually a substring kind of function, I would not recommend it. But anyway it depends on the way you want to use it.

Comment: @KEREN . strpos is use to Find the position of the first occurrence of a substring in a string.. you can use it as recommended for any instance of string.

Comment: @KEREN ... in your case I am not sure why it is happening.. but I'm sure there's something wrong to the type of value return from the model... STRPOS however will make sure that whatever "content the variable has" it will treat as String no matter what.

Comment: @KEREN... You must use STRPOS if you're dealing with variables that you're not sure if it would return a string-type or not.. because even a variable is numeric it will treat the value as string.

Comment: @KEREN.. You should also use STRPOS according to the definition itself.